# Add line number at the end of each line in a text file

Tags: linux, command-line, perl

I have a text file which contains thousands of lines with same links. I want append the line number at the end of each line. For example;

```
https://example.com/
https://example.com/
```

these links would become:

```
https://example.com/1
https://example.com/2
```

and so on.
I tried using the following code:

```
sed -n 'p;=' file | paste -d":" - -
```

However, it printed all the lines of the text file and the line number in the terminal in the following manner:

```
https://example.com/:1
https://example.com/:2
```

Comment: Are you open to a perl one-liner solution?

Comment: @Toto yes, i'm open to a perl one-liner solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This perl one-liner does the job:

```perl
perl -i -ape 's/$/$./' inputfile
```

Where `$` stands for end of line and `$.` is the current line number.